# State in Link is not setting, returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
<Link
        to={{
            pathname: `/blogs/${props.blog._id}`,
            state: {
                blog: props.blog,
            },
        }}
    >
```

Above the code im setting my state to be sent with the to object so that i can harness it in the next page and then display the blog accordingly.

However,

```
function Blog(props) {
console.log(props.location.state);
return (
    <div className="container blog">
        <h1 className="blog-title">Hello Heyhs h</h1>
    </div>
);
```

}

the above console.log gives undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your route definition for `Blog` component should look like below,

```
...
<Route path="/blogs/:blogId">< Blog/></Route>
...
```

If that is the case you are not passing the required props. You should change it as below,

```
<Route path="/blogs/:blogId" render={(props) =><Blog {...props}/>} />
```

OR

```
<Route path="/blogs/:blogId" component={Blog}/>
```

in this way you can pass the `location` as a prop in react router.

Comment: Yes, <Route path="/blogs/:id" component={Blog}></Route> is exactly how im using it. Still nothing.